# Nginx Wordpress Permalinks without index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I have nginx running with php 7 fpm.
My Wordpress permalinks are setup with `/%postname%/`. assuming my domain is `example.com` I want to have permalinks like that: `example.com/postname/` But this leads to an error. I can find the post with this link: `example.com/index.php?postname/`

How do I get rid of the `index.php?` in the links?

### Edit

My Nginx config

```
server {
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location ~\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $args;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
        }

        location /wordpress/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
        }
}
```

Comment: The rather overcomplicated official example is [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/). If you need help with your specific configuration, you will need to add it to your question.

Comment: @RichardSmith I added my config. I had about a thousand different configs in the last days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question implies that WordPress is installed at `location /`, so I am not sure why you have a `location /wordpress` also.

There are some issues with your configuration.

The value for REQUEST_URI should be set to `$request_uri` which is probably already the default value in the `fastcgi_params` file. This is the parameter that `index.php` uses to decode the pretty permalink.

Delete the line `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $args;`.

Your `try_files` statement is missing a `?`. Use either:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Or:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

I have found that passing `$args` to `/index.php` is not necessary with WordPress.

Comment: no my wordpress installation is on /var/www/wordpress, my domain points to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/wordpress/ I changed your input, that leads to "that page can't be found" on example.com and to real 404 on example.com/postname/

Comment: example.com/index.php?postname is broken, when changing $args to $request_uri

Comment: In response to your first comment: Is there a reverse proxy?

Comment: In response to your second comment: Why do you need `example.com/index.php?postname` to work?

Comment: I don't need it to work, but it worked before... so that was kind of off-topic. What exactly do you mean with reverse proxy? in my nginx there is none. My Strato Domain is routed via "proxy mode"

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot proxy `example.com/postname` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/postname` - you may be overcomplicating your configuration by adding an extra `wordpress` into the pretty permalink.

Comment: Thats exactly what I try to achieve. I am an absolute nginx newbie by the way ;-).

Comment: If you change `root` to `root /var/www/wordpress;`, you should be able to change Strato Domain "proxy mode" to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot we're at 99%. only thing, that's not working is when i click on settings or settings/general I get redirected to example.com all other settings pages are working

Comment: OMG today is my day... sry for that dump question.. and thanks  a lot for yout patience and the solution!